# Spyder Kernels "module not found" on Ubuntu VM

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, kernel, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

I am trying to connect a spyder kernel with my remote Ubuntu machine and was following [this guide](https://medium.com/@halmubarak/connecting-spyder-ide-to-a-remote-ipython-kernel-25a322f2b2be). Installing spyder kernels using `sudo pip install spyder-kernels` worked fine.

However, when trying to run:

`python -m spyder_kernels.console — matplotlib=’inline’ — ip=my.vm.ip.address. -f=./remotemachine.json`

I receive the following error on my VM:

`Error while finding module specification for 'spyder_kernels.console' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder_kernels')`

My remote VM uses `Python 3.7.7` and is hosted by Google's cloud platform.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that running `sudo pip install`, you're using the root user's Python installation, and not the user installation you eventually run your command from.

Try using either `python -m pip install spyder-kernels` or `sudo python -m spyder_kernels.console ...`. Preferably you would not run either command as root.

Comment: is there any documentation: I am having the same issue and cannot find any correct solution. Links to docs are broken, e.g.  https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html